# Is there a safer way to make preprocess changes?

Tags: 7, theming

I recently made changes to template and node.tpl files for my theme. Is there a recommended way of implementing preprocess changes as to not hard code them into these files (in case of theme updates) or am I going to have to re-code them after theme udpates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an ideal world, you would create a [sub-theme](http://drupal.org/node/225125) off of your master theme.  For example, most people don't use the [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) or [Zen](http://drupal.org/project/zen) themes directly; rather they use the starter kit which is included as the basis for the sub-theme.

The sub-theme will inherit features from the base theme, but allow you to customize as needed.  When the base theme gets updated, the sub-theme doesn't get touched.

Whether you can retrofit your theme to actually be a sub-theme depends on your situation, but I suspect it is possible.

Comment: I use adaptivetheme... which is the core for pixture_reloaded theme... so I would only make changes to the pixture_reloaded theme in my case? EDIT: Just found a possible issue, I have to edit the node.tpl file... and the sub-theme doesn't have one.

Comment: When a sub-theme doesn't have a file, it uses the one from the bases theme.  You can copy that one into your sub-theme, and then edit it.